# Swift: Pass facebook login graphRequest result between viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, authentication, uiviewcontroller

I'm using facebook sdk to implement a facebook login to my app. In the viewcontroller where I implement the login I also do a facebook graphrequest which allows me to get information about the current user.

The code for this graph request is:

```
        let graphRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in            
        if error != nil {                
            //handle error
            println("graphrequest error")
        } else {
            self.firstName = result.valueForKey("first_name") as? String
        }
    })
```

The user information comes back from the closure as the "result" paramater which can then be decomposed into its components ie firstname as above.

I know I can pass the first name value (and all other values individually) from this viewcontroller to the next. My question is (for efficiency) how can I pass the actual "result" itself (which contains all the user data) between viewcontrollers?

To pass it I figured I have to know its TYPE, looking at the facebook sdk info I thought I'd discovered the type is a FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult but when I pass this to the next viewcontroller it shows up as nil. During debugging I PO'd the result and ended up with the following (a fake test user)

```
    Printing description of result:
{
    email = "wvjuyaz_greenestein_1428614609@tfbnw.net";
    "first_name" = Barbara;
    gender = female;
    id = 1391655294490653;
    "last_name" = Greenestein;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/1391655294490653/";
    locale = "en_US";
    "middle_name" = Amichehgcdjh;
    name = "Barbara Amichehgcdjh Greenestein";
    timezone = 0;
    "updated_time" = "2015-04-09T21:23:30+0000";
    verified = 0;
}
```

What type is this? and how do I pass it (in full) to the next viewcontroller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thx john for your information. i didn't realize it at the time but i could just make a facebook query for the user information from any viewcontroller whilst i was logged in. I didn't have to pass the information myself between viewcontrollers.  Essentially i could just run the graph request code listed above in my question in a different viewcontroller. If I need to pass the JSON code around in future I'll follow your instructions. thx

Answer (score 0):

That data type is JSON dictionary- essentially the standard for the web http://json.org

There are several ways you can pass this data around, but probably the easiest way is to store it as a string through user defaults and retrieve it on the other side independently.

result.valueForKey("first_name")

If you are unfamiliar with JSON, I'd suggest using a library such as swiftyjson or alamofire as dealing with JSON natively in swift remains a sore spot.

Answer (score 0):

make a class for user and initialize it's object with the data returned from the json and then pass that object anywhere